# Gstreamer with Bad Quality. Packet Loss

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspberry-pi2, python-gstreamer

I'm new to Gstreamer and for some reason the quality of my stream is off. It looks like there are some packet loss. I created a pipeline on my Raspberry Pi 2 and another pipeline on my PC. Could someone explain to me why is this happening and/or how to make it better? The image starts completely gray but I can shake off the gray until it looks better but there still some packet loss.

Raspberry Pi 2 Pipeline:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
raspivid -n -t 0 -rot 270 -w 960 -h 720 -fps 30 -b 6000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 ! udpsink host=***YOUR_PC_IP*** port=5000
```

PC Pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
```

Comment: I've worked with Raspberry Pi in the past and while they are awesome for a lot of things, we easily brought them to their knees when the processing power and memory was pushed to the limit.  When you are running the stream is the load and/or memory usage high to the point it would affect the stream?

Comment: I think the problem is with the Gstreamer pipeline. My friend runs his script using another streamer and the image looks perfect but I need to use Gstreamer

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by packet loss in more detail?  There are artifacts on the screen?  Stuttering?  Frame drops?  Is the stream delayed a few seconds?  When you say your friends script runs fine, do you mean for the receiving side or the sending side?

Comment: Here are some images of what it looks like. http://imgur.com/a/mquy6 At first it is all gray but I can shake it all off and after a while it looks perfect but if there is movement blurs start appearing again. No frame drops and no delays. My friend's script is from the receiving end.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm experiencing the same problem.